# java/Modbus Error in reading the response in jamod

Tags: error-handling

Hi
   iam using jamod api to communicate with meter via modem by sending commands and reading all the register values from the meter.the command is received successfully by the modem at meter end but iam not able to read all the registers from the meter all at a time. iam getting the following error
Last request: 01 04 05 13 00 08 00 c5
CRC Error in received frame: 0 bytes: 
execute try 3 error: I/O exception - failed to read

How to solve these errors and get the reading from the meter. please help...?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by setting the transaction delay to 50ms.

```
transaction.setTransDelayMS(50);
transaction.execute();
```